# What is this? (auto drop-down)

Tags: c#

I store a list of names in a text file. When I enter any single character on a text boc position on the main form, I need a small window to display and list the term I may choose to fill in. I don't what this is called to search the iNternet if there exists a similar source code for me to use.
Thank you.

Comment: Apologies, but I can't figure out what you're looking for. Can you edit your question and add some clarification please? Thanks.

Comment: Winforms?  WPF?  ASP.NET?  You'll need to provide a bit more info to help us help you.  As written, your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

Search terms you may find helpful: Autocomplete and  combobox

Comment: perhaps more appropriate as a comment?

Comment: @Mat: I generally use google for that....

Comment: @Mat: No, I mean that's what I use google for: finding related terms....

Comment: As Mat suggested, I posted this as an answer because that was the whole question being asked. I probably should have also flagged the question as off-topic, since this kind of question is more appropriate for chat than a full-scale SO question.